# Узнать о завершении async-метода в синхронном

Tags: c#, алгоритм, async-await

Есть два метода, один из которых асинхронен. `Main` вызывается в новом потоке и вызывает асинхронный метод, который по окончанию заносит в поле результат выполнения.
В `Main` нужно дождаться выполнения `MakeAnalysisRequest`, после чего вернуть поле.

```
public string Main(byte[] imageFile)
{
  MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFile);
  return JSONanswer;      
}


static async void MakeAnalysisRequest(byte[] imageFile)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  //и т.д.
  JSONanswer = contentString;  //JSONanswer - поле текущего класса
}
```

Нынешний метод `Main` при первом обращении возвращает пустое поле, при втором - результаты первого и так далее.
Вероятно, асинхронный `MakeAnalysisRequest` завершается позже, чем `Main`.
Как всё-таки заставить `Main` ожидать завершения второго метода?

Comment: @РусланЯгупов , спасибо, на досуге обязательно почитаю. Проблема разрешилась проще, чем я думал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не должно хотеться синхронно дождаться окончания асинхронной операции. Это очень плохая идея, и нивелирует все достоинства async/await.

Кроме того, `async void` и общение функций через глобальное состояние (статическую переменную) — ещё одна крайне плохая идея. В любом случае, переделайте метод `MakeAnalysisRequest`, чтобы он возвращал не `void`:

```
static async Task<string> MakeAnalysisRequest(byte[] imageFile)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    //и т.д.
    return contentString;
}
```

Теперь по-хорошему ваш вызов должен выглядеть так:

```
public async Task<string> Main(byte[] imageFile)
{
    var responce = await MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFile);
    // если всё ещё нужно, запишите в поле JSONanswer
    return responce;
}
```

---

В качестве временного хака, позволяющего использовать синхронный метод, *может* сработать такой отвратительный код (а может и привести к deadlock'у):

```
public string Main(byte[] imageFile)
{
    var responceTask = Task.Run(() => MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFile));
    var responce = responceTask.Result;
    // если всё ещё нужно, запишите в поле JSONanswer
    return responce;
}
```

Постарайтесь переделать вашу программу, чтобы такие хаки не были нужны.

Comment: спасибо, практически так и оформил. Только начал изучать async. Пробовал использовать "костыль" (.Result) - получил deadlock. В результате переосмыслил архитектуру и исправил все вызывающие методы под async - всё заработало как надо.

Comment: @MihailPirogovsky: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!